# Let $V = \{ A \in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) | AJ = JA^t\}$ , how to compute the dimension of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $J = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & -9 \\
  -1 & 0 & 4 \\
  9 & -4 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $V = \{ A \in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) | AJ = JA^t\}$

How one can compute the dimension of $V$?

Do I have to solve $A = (a_{ij})$ explicitly?

---

Following are my trial:

(1) Since $J$ is skew-symmetric matrix, $AJ= JA^t = -(AJ)^t$. So letting $B=AJ$, then the degrees of freedom of $B$ is $\frac{3(3-1)}{2}=3$. And since $J$ has three d.o.f, $A$ have three d.o.f, so dimesion of $V$ is $3$.

(2) Let $A = (a_{ij})$ and compute $AJ, JA^t$ explicitly.

\begin{align}
AJ = \begin{pmatrix}
-a_{12} + 9 a_{13} & a_{11} - 4 a_{13} & - 9 a_{11} + 4 a_{12} \\
-a_{22} + 9 a_{23} & a_{21} - 4 a_{23} & - 9 a_{21} + 4 a_{22} \\
-a_{32} + 9 a_{33} & a_{31} - 4 a_{33} & - 9 a_{31} + 4 a_{32} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
And
\begin{align}
JA^t = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{12} - 9 a_{13} & a_{22} - 9 a_{23} & a_{32} - 9 a_{33}  \\ 
- a_{11} + 4 a_{13} & - a_{12} + 4 a_{23} & - a_{31} + 4 a_{33} \\
9 a_{11} - 4 a_{12} & 9 a_{21} - 4 a_{22} & 9 a_{31} - 4 a_{32}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Now solving $AJ = JA^t$,  among $9$ equations there are $3$ diagonal and $3$ off-diagonal equations and hence there are $9-6=3$ ...

Comment: Not sure if it was obvious, but $J^t=-J$

Comment: $J$ is a nonzero skew-symmetric matrix. By a change of orthonormal basis, you may assume that $J=a\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0\\ &&0}$ for some $a\ne0$.

Comment: @user1551, Hello, from the property of skew-symmetric matrix, I updated my posts. But I am not sure whether it is mathematically correct.

Comment: @phy_math No, it isn't correct. $J$ is a fixed matrix. It has no room for change. $V$ should be four-dimensional.

Comment: @user1551, can you give me a more detailed explanation about the dimension of $V$ is $4$?